# How TreeMap searches successor for given Entry?

Tags: java, algorithm, treemap

I am a bit confused on the follwoing method of `java.util.TreeMap:`

```
static <K,V> TreeMap.Entry<K,V> successor(Entry<K,V> t) {
        if (t == null)
            return null;
        else if (t.right != null) {
            Entry<K,V> p = t.right;
            while (p.left != null)
                p = p.left;
            return p;
        } else {
            Entry<K,V> p = t.parent;
            Entry<K,V> ch = t;
            while (p != null && ch == p.right) {
                ch = p;
                p = p.parent;
            }
            return p;
        }
    }
```

This method is used in TreeMap's *containsValue* method. And it is told to retrieve successor of first Entry and successor of previously retrieved successor and so on. 
So this above method retrieves Entries of the whole TreeMap. 
But I don't understand very well how it works, how it seeks successor?

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a standard binary tree traversal algorithm (in-order, or symmetric order, traversal).  If you don't understand how binary trees work, I'd research that first, because otherwise it's just going to be too complicated to answer here.

Comment: @ajb thanks for pointing out traversal types in particular in-order which is really used here.

Answer (score 5):

This works on a binary search tree, and it uses the following facts:

1. The 'leftest' leaf in a sub-tree, indicates the smallest key.
2. A parent is always bigger then any node of its left subtree (definition of binary search tree).

So, this is exactly what the algorithm is doing:

1. It searches if there is a right sub-tree, if there is, the leftest leaf there is the sucessor, since it is the smallest value which is bigger then the given node.
2. If there is no right sub-tree, it means that the successor is NOT in the sub-tree where `t` is the root of, so it searches the first parent where `t` is a node in its left sub-tree.

**Example:**

```
           4
          / \
         /   \ 
        /     \
       /       \
      2         6
     /         / \
    /         /   \
   1         5     7
```

- Successor of 2: since 2 has no right sub-tree, its the first parent
  that 2 is in the left sub-tree, which is 4 - as expected (the `else` case in the code).
- Successor of 4 is the "leftest leaf" of the right sub-tree, which is 5 as expected.

---

Also, as a 'quiz' make sure you understand when the condition `p != null` in `while (p != null && ch == p.right)` is not met.

Comment: Thanks for good response! Condition p!=null means that parent of provided Entry t is not equal to null. But why in this while loop we traverse from p to its topmost right parent. Why don't we take just first right parent but cycle through all right parents? In case of 7 successor() method would retrieve 4. Why is that?

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi The condition `p != null` is met when you are looking for the successor of the "last" element in the tree. Regarding your question - a node does not have a "right parent" it has a single parent! we need to find the first time we branched right (looking down-up) in the tree, so we are iterating the loop until it is found.

Comment: There is no such thing as the "right parent": the parent is only one, so it is always the "upper parent". You are looking for a parent or an ancestor such that you are in its left subtree, hence the loop.

Comment: Right parent is parent of right child !  It seems to me that condition p!=null means that provided Entry t does not have right child and has right parent. Why is 4 successor of 7?

Comment: 4 is not successor of 7, 7 has no successor, the algorithm will yield `null` for finding the successor of 7.

Comment: I do not understand! I see that this second while loop very well returns 4 as successor of 7. Thanks for your picture. It made me see the tree search better.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi No, when getting to `p == 4`, you will then 'see' that `p != null` and `p.right == 6` and also `ch == 6`, thus `p.right == ch`, and the loop will not break, so you will set `ch = p` (which is 4) and `p = p.parent` (which is null, since p has no parent), and continue. Next iteration you check if `p != null`, you fail and return `p`, which is `null`.

Comment: I got it! Thanks! Your picture shows that successor of 7 is null!

Answer (score 3):

The logic behind this method is as follows:

- The successor of a `null` node does not exist
- The successor of any node with a right subtree is the leftmost leaf node of its right subtree (i.e. "go right, then walk down and to the left as far as you can; that would be the successor).
- The successor of any node without a right subtree is its first ancestor node of which the current node is located in a left subtree.

This logic is expressed in the three branches of the conditional chain: the first `if` deals with `null`, the second walks the left subtree of the right branch, and its `else` walks up the tree structure in search of ancestor such that the current subtree was on its left.

Here is how the search may look when the algorithm needs to find a successor, and the right subtree exists: the current node is shown in red, its successor is shown in green. The algorithm goes one step right, and then proceeds all the way to the left.

[image: Right subtree]

Here is how the search may look when the algorithm needs to find a successor, but there is no right subtree: the current node is shown in red, its successor is shown in green. The algorithm goes up, checking if we came from a left subtree. For the parent of the current node the answer is "no", because the current node is in the right subtree. For the parent of the parent the answer is "yes", so it is returned as the current node's successor.

[image: Left subtree]

Comment: Thank very much! Now I realized how in-order successor and predecessor is found in method I posted. This is just as depicted on these great pictures. Now I know how it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TreeMap internally uses Red-Black Tree data structure and any Red-Black tree has to be a Binary Search Tree.

The concept of finding a successor is like finding the NEXT suitable element/object/node.

If we look closely at Amit's example and sort it's nodes then they would be:

```
1,2,4,5,6,7
```

Now if we are intended to find successor for 4 it would be 5 and it is more easily understood. Now, Note the point ***the "leftest leaf" of the right sub-tree*** as mentioned by Amit.

Similarly in case of 2 it would be 4. Mapping it with Amit's First condition ***since 2 has no right sub-tree, its the first parent that 2 is in the left sub-tree***

Reference: 
Red Black tree | Introduction to Red Black trees | Data structure
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCM-yUTYGmrNvKOCcAl21g3w

Some really good reference to understand first the actual underlying Data Structure!